# What's the best way to print out a long number with dots in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to print out millions(or more) like 321.100.401 . Do you have any good method?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it to use periods as the separator, `toLocaleString` will convert a number to a string using the current locale.

```
var num = 5000;
console.log(num.toLocaleString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Using_locales) with an appropriate parameter like `'de-DE'`.

```js
document.write((321100401).toLocaleString('de-DE'));
```